# How to hide a TabBarItem in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, tabs, xamarin.ios

I have a Storyboard with a `TabBarController` and six subviews as Tabs. The `TabBarController` and each Tab has a Controller Class assigned.
The content of some tabs is loaded from a server. In some cases there is no content for a tab and for this case I want to hide the TabBarItem.

I've tried (just for testing)

```
this.TabBarController.TabBar.Items [0].Enabled = false;
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I hide a single TabBarItems? I've searched Google, StackOverflow and the Xamarin Forum but found no solution for my problem.
The only solution I've found was to remove the subview from the subviews-array, but in this case I cannot simply "reactivate" the tab if I want to show the tab again.

Answer (score 1):

In case of  UITabBar:

```
UITabBar sampleTabBar;

public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            sampleTabBar = new UITabBar ();
            sampleTabBar.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (10f, 64f, this.View.Frame.Width - 10, 50f);

            var tabBarItem = new UITabBarItem ("TAB BAR ITEM", null, 4);
            sampleTabBar.Items = new UITabBarItem[]{ tabBarItem };
            sampleTabBar.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
                Console.WriteLine ("tab bar button item slected");

             //Disable Tab Bar item here
                tabBarItem.Enabled = false;
                tabBarItem.Title = "Disabled now";
            };

            this.View.AddSubview (sampleTabBar);
        }
```

tabBarItem.Image property also can be used for getting the result.

```
1) Set a placeholder image as default.
2) Populate images from array/source to uibarButtonItem.
3) Use placeholder image wherever need to hide uibarbuttonitem.
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. But this way the TabBarItem is still visible and just deactivated. I want to completely hide the TabBarItem.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to completely hide the `UITabbarItem` you will need to  remove the `UIViewController` from the `UITabbarController` like so:

```
    var tbViewControllers = new List<UIViewController> (TabBarController.ViewControllers);
    tbViewControllers.RemoveAt (2); // remove whatever index you need.
    TabBarController.ViewControllers = tbViewControllers.ToArray ();
```

but you will need to keep a reference to all the `UIViewControllers` you want and add it back in like so:

```
    var tbViewControllers = new List<UIViewController> (TabBarController.ViewControllers);
    tbViewControllers.Insert (2, new RemvoedViewController());
    TabBarController.ViewControllers = tbViewControllers.ToArray ();
```